# ¿Cómo realizar una captura de imagen de una cámara WEB mediante C#?

Tags: c#, imagen, aforge

Buscando una solución a mi problema encontré la librería Aforge.NET pero solo encuentro información sobre cómo realizar captura pero de video, yo ocupo realizar captura de imagen y guardarla.

Mi proyecto será en una aplicación de consola, por lo que no está disponible el uso de elementos picturebox, etc.

Comment: tengo un ejemplo en C# con picturebox.

Comment: quizas esto te ayude https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/forums/how-to-capture-image-using-webcam-in-console-application